# how to target an auto generated list in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I want to target the auto generated list and its items in css, the original codes are here http://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/Ioype *-By Jason Mayes-* and I want to target the list in "**Query 1: My latest tweet**" I did change this in JS (`"maxTweets": 1,`) to (`"maxTweets": 5,`).

Right now, I have many lists & list items customized already in my css sheet. so if I just copy his css my other lists are going to be effected too. Any way to target the generated list of tweets with this id (`example1`) ??? I already tried to put a class in it and then tried this (`ul.tweetss li.tweetss`) but it didn't work without effecting all other list & list items.

> The final goal is to customize the tweets are generated by this javascript plugin in a complete website ..

Thanks in advance for your time and effort ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: http://codepen.io/irvingv8/pen/dWemVy

I used sass to encapsulate all of his styles with a `.encapsulated` class and added a div with said class wrapping all his html. you can get the css you need by clicking "view compiled CSS" in the CSS tab.

Do not forget the div with the `.encapsulated` class wrapping the twitter feed HTML!

Comment: Thanks a lot @StormRage

Comment: Just a reminder to make sure you are using the latest version currently 17 due to a breaking change.